# Invisible redirects (to the client) via Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement to send requests to either page A or page B based on userID e.g. a simple A/B testing service. The logic for working out what page to send the user to is all done. However I'm trying to work out the best way to implement the final step e.g. the actual redirect.

The redirect must be invisible to the client so if they request /foo/a but my app decides they should see /foo/b then the client should still think they are seeing /foo/a content. The application working out which page a user sees is a Spring boot application and I have a "catch all" method in my controller that can handle any request and apply the logic to work out what url to actually call. Ideally what I would like is to take the HttpServletRequest to ensure I have all the cookies etc, make the http call to the new path and return the result of this back to the client.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-url-proxy/blob/master/spring-boot-url-proxy/src/main/java/com/github/ulisesbocchio/spring/boot/proxy/GithubProxyApplication.java#L83 It appears to proxy an HTTP call in Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of what you're describing could look like this:

```
@Controller
public class ABController {

    //Catch All GET Requests
    @GetMapping("/**")
    public String getPage(HttpServletRequest request) {

        //Access the Spring Security Context (if you're using this).
        String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        //Access the HttpServletRequest
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        //Perform some decision logic for select the appropriate web page to return
        if(username.equals("someUser")) {
            return "b";
        } else {
            return "a";
        }
    }
}
```